# GitLab: No user or key was provided

Tags: git, gitlab

```
root@localhost:/home/git/gitlab-satellites/root/rep# git push
Counting objects: 6834, done.
Delta compression using up to 3 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5339/5339), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6833/6833), 13.52 MiB | 17.65 MiB/s, done.
Total 6833 (delta 1370), reused 6833 (delta 1370)


remote: GitLab: No user or key was provided.
To /home/git/repositories/root/rep.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/git/repositories/root/rep.git'
```

---

```
Ubuntu 15.04
Apache2
GitLab 7.12.0
GitLab Shell 2.6.3
GitLab API v3
Ruby 2.2.2p95
Rails 4.1.11
```

---

```
cd /home/git/gitlab-satellites/root/rep; git remote -v
origin  /home/git/repositories/root/rep.git (fetch)
origin  /home/git/repositories/root/rep.git (push)
```

Comment: А Вы создали на gitlab пользователя и привязали к нему ключ?

Comment: Всё создано всё привязано

Comment: Это очень странно, что веб обвязка работает с репой на отлично, а в командной строке прям на сервере не хочет пушить, что под рутом, что под git'ом. Логи полностью пустые!

Comment: Находясь в папке `/home/git/gitlab-satellites/root/rep` выполните `git remote -v` и допишите вывод этой команды в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

вы подключаетесь к репозиторию как к набору локальных файлов:

```
/home/git/repositories/root/rep.git
```

в этом случае не происходит *ssh-подключения* и *hook-и*, прописанные в этом репозитории, отклоняют внесённые изменения.

образно говоря, вы «зашли на кухню с чёрного хода».

а заходить надо «с парадного», ровно таким же образом, как и при подключении к этому репозиторию с других компьютеров (зависит от настроек установленного *gitlab-а*):

```
$ git clone https://ваш.сервер/путь/к/репозиторию
```

или:

```
$ git clone git@ваш.сервер:путь/к/репозиторию
```

---

как исправить ситуацию, не клонируя репозиторий вновь? исправьте *url* для (дефолтного) репозитория *origin* (подставьте правильный *url* для нужного репозитория):

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://ваш.сервер/путь/к/репозиторию
```