# Git, web-интерфейс Kallithea, ошибка в перехватчике запросов

Tags: python, git, githooks

Поставил и сконфигурировал на git-сервер в локалке на *Open Suse 13.1* web-морду [kallithea](https://kallithea-scm.org), все нормально, единственно что по установке там кое что не документировано, и возможно она не умеет сама цеплять репозитории, но дело в другом.

Создал я в ней пустой репозиторий и склонировал его, добавил в локальный нужные файлы, скоммитил и сделал `push`.   И *hook Каллифеи* не поймал имени пользователя.

Сомневаюсь, что кто то сталкивался с подобным, но я не знаю что делать.
Полазил по конфигам, ничего не нашел, авторизация на морде проходит.

Вот что выдало (звездочки это юзернейм или имя проекта):

```
> git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/*****/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Counting objects: 3943, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3781/3781), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3943/3943), 73.76 MiB | 2.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 3943 (delta 1572), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "hooks/pre-receive", line 34, in <module>
remote:     main()
remote:   File "hooks/pre-receive", line 30, in main
remote:     _handler(repo_path, push_data, os.environ)
remote:   File "/srv/www/htdocs/Kallithea-0.2.1/kallithea/lib/hooks.py", line 373, in <lambda>
remote:     handle_git_receive(repo_path, revs, env, hook_type='pre'))
remote:   File "/srv/www/htdocs/Kallithea-0.2.1/kallithea/lib/hooks.py", line 395, in handle_git_receive
remote:     extras = _extract_extras(env)
remote:   File "/srv/www/htdocs/Kallithea-0.2.1/kallithea/lib/utils2.py", line 644, in _extract_extras
remote:     raise Exception('Missing key %s in os.environ %s' % (e, rc_extras))
remote: Exception: Missing key 'username' in os.environ {}
To root@10.27.14.97:/home/git/git_repo/*****
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'root@10.27.14.97:/home/git/git_repo/*****
```

UPD:

```
/path/to/local_rep/ > git remote -v
origin  root@10.27.14.97:/home/git/git_repo/**** (fetch)
origin  root@10.27.14.97:/home/git/git_repo/**** (push)
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста, вывод `git remote -v`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin приложил

Comment: вы именно так и настроили *kallithea*? может быть, `url` всё-таки должен выглядеть как-то так: `http://ваш.сервер/репозиторий`, а не `root@ваш.сервер:/home/git/git_repo/репозиторий`?

Comment: посмотрите на, вероятно, схожую [ошибку с *gitlab-ом*](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434370/178576).

Comment: вот ссылка на [документацию, где приводятся примеры url-ов](http://kallithea.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/general.html#permanent-repository-urls).

Comment: когда я выполнил команду по конфигурации первая тут: https://pythonhosted.org/Kallithea/setup.html?highlight=username то указал этот путь на сервере, возможно вы идете в верном направлении, т.к. Каллифея при создании использовала такую http ссылку, а вот без абсолютного пути clone не находит репозиторий значит надо прописать элейес для гита возможно?

Comment: вот [здесь](https://pythonhosted.org/Kallithea/setup.html) путь к каталогу с репозиториями указывается в команде `paster` параметром `--repos`. если вы устанавливали *kalithea* из пакетов, вероятно, должен быть где-то конфигурационный файл, где этот путь и надо указывать.

Comment: пустой репозиторий вы, надеюсь, создавали именно через веб-интерфейс? создался ли при этом одноимённый каталог где-то в глубине `/srv/repos`? ссылка для клонирования вида `http://ваш.сервер/репозиторий` (или что-то в этом духе) в веб-интерфейсе присутствует? если присутствует, что получается при `git clone эта.ссылка`?

Comment: репозиторий создал через веб интерфейс, каталог создается http доступ к git не настроен и не нужен, сслыка _http://root@10.27.14.97/my_project/', клонируется по http без ошибок, пуш выполняется с ошибкой fatal: Authentication failed for '_http://root@10.27.14.97/my_progect'

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25952/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-olegup).

Comment: а вот по ssh если настроить в .git/config url=ssh://root@10.27.14.97/gome/git/git_repo/myproject пишет: